# What does version in Terraform state mean?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm using s3 bucket as remote state. I'm just confused what the value of version ("version": 4) in tfstate file means.

```
{
  "version": 4,
  "terraform_version": "1.2.1",
  "serial": 402,
  "lineage": "0e5a03fc-1b6f-e56b-8c9b-a0e0a1756f12",
  "outputs": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "module": "module.aws_cloudwatch",
      "mode": "managed",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the version of the terraform state file. The version is managed by terrafrom itself.

**In a Terraform state file, there are three "types of versions":**

- The syntax version of the state file itself
- The versions of the provider used to create each of the resources
- The Terraform version used to initially create the state file

**The versions of a state file may change due to the following:**

- An updated version of the Terraform core works with the state file
- An updated provider is used to apply resources
- This one can't change, as the state file is only every created for the first time once
- The versions within a state file can only be updated (and are only updated) by running a terraform apply